Are there conditions under which the bracketing numbers are bounded by the covering numbers?
For a function class $\mathcal{F}$, we have the following two definitions:
Definition 1. Given two functions $l,r$ not necessarily elements of $\mathcal{F}$, a bracket $[l,r]$ is defined as the class of functions $l\leq f\leq r$ where the ordering is defined pointwise, an $\varepsilon$-bracket is a bracket with $\|l-r\|\leq\varepsilon$. The bracketing entropy $N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)$ of $\mathcal{F}$ with respect to a (semi-)norm $\|\cdot\|$ is defined as the minimum number of $\varepsilon$-brackets needed to cover $\mathcal{F}$.
Definition 2. The covering number $N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)$ is the minimal number of $\varepsilon$-balls $\{g:\|f-g\|<\varepsilon\}$ needed to cover $\mathcal{F}$. The centers need not to belong to $\mathcal{F}$.
Is it well known that $N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)\leq N_{[]}(2\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)$ and $N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_\infty)=N_{[]}(2\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_\infty)$.
Question. For my specific problem, I have a VC class $\mathcal{F}$, which is known to have welcoming properties with respect to the entropy numbers, but for a given proof, there are only results available for bracketing entropy numbers. And so before engulfing in a complicated and tedious proof to extend the result to uniform entropy (if even possible), I wanted to ask if there are conditions on $\mathcal{F}$ such that
\begin{equation}
N_{[]}(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)\leq L N(\varepsilon,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|)
\end{equation}
where $L$ is a constant and $\|\cdot\|$ is either an Orlicz norm or an $L^p$ norm with $p<\infty$.
For some background context, I am investigating maximal inequalities for totally bounded permissible VC classes $\mathcal{F}$ for empirical processes coming from $\beta$-mixing sequences. In the i.i.d. case, there is a very welcoming inequality
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\sup_{f\in\mathcal{F}}|\sqrt{n}(P_n(f)-P(f))|\leq L J(1,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_2)\|F\|_{2}
\end{equation}
where $F$ is an envelope for $\mathcal{F}$ and $J(1,\mathcal{F},\|\cdot\|_2)$ is the uniform entropy integral. In case of $\beta$-mixing sequences, a similar result is available under the assumption that the bracketing integral is finite, and even if the uniform entropy integral is finite.
However, if one only assumes that the uniform entropy integral is finite, then the inequality comes with additional terms which make certain applications impossible (applications concerning the convergence rate of $M$-estimators). In particular, the inequality comes with terms that relate to the diameter of $\mathcal{F}$ in such a way that if the diameter converges to zero sufficiently fast, then the inequality diverges to infinity, while trivially the supremum on the l.h.s. converges to zero (see, for example, proposition 3 in this paper). Hence as a bonus question, I am additionally interested in the following:
Question. Does there exists an extension to the maximal inequality above for $\beta$-mixing sequences indexed by VC classes where one only assumes that the uniform entropy integral is finite where the inequality remains stable regardless of the diameter to $\mathcal{F}$.
As a final remark, any VC class of bounded functions has a finite uniform entropy integral as a consequence to a famous inequality for VC classes in terms of their covering number.
Thank you in advance!
